# cmake install to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX root

Tags: cmake

Cmake's install command

```
install(TARGETS MyTarget LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

requires me to install shared libraries to a subfolder. It seems the LIBRARY DESTINATION is not optional. But I need to install the .so/.dll/.dynlib files directly to the folder the user specifies via CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. The background here is: the library is a plugin for an application and it needs to go into a .plugin in $HOME)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
INSTALL( TARGETS MyTarget LIBRARY DESTINATION .)
```

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (install):
  install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!

Comment: `DESTINATION` or `LIBRARY DESTINATION`? What kind of target is `MyTarget`? What OS do you use? Works for me on Windows.

Comment: Just want to add that you do definitely want to use ```.``` as the destination when installing to the prefix root, rather than ```${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}``` or else things like CPack won't work for whatever reason.